# event('response-body') always empty

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Using the following statement I used to get the HTTP body in Orbeon 3.9 from the server when there's an error, but in Orbeon 4.7 I get nothing and the message ends at "Body: "

```
        <xforms:submission id="get-user-groups" serialization="none" method="get" resource="http://www.example.org/xxx" replace="instance" instance="user-groups">
            <xforms:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal">
                A submission error occurred: <xforms:output value="event('error-type')"/>; Status: <xforms:output value="event('response-status-code')"/>; URI: <xforms:output value="event('resource-uri')"/>; Headers: <xforms:output value="event('response-headers')"/>; Body: <xforms:output value="event('response-body')"/>
            </xforms:message>
        </xforms:submission>
```

Any hints? I looked at http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging#TOC-Development-configuration, but that only hints at logging. This is about telling the user what's up.

It appears to me as if there's a bug in supporting event('response-body'). orbeon.log has no info

Comment: This might be a regression. Can you open an [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/new)?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2336